# In PyCharm, should I use embedded terminal or running console?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, I have 2 methods to run my code:

1. press `ctrl + alt + F10`, then the code will run in running console.
2. go to embedded terminal, run the code by `./filename.py`.

Which method should I use? Or is there a better method? I tried method 1, but problem is some features are missing, like press up arrow for history command, or when use `pdb.set_trace()` to enter debug mode, the auto-complete feature in running console behaves strangely: for example, in debug mode of running console, when entering a `[]`, the cursor automatically jumps out of the square brackets and do not allow me to type anything in the square brackets. However, there must be a reason why running console exists, right? Otherwise there should only be the embedded terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better method is to set the "Emulate terminal in output console" option in the settings of the run configuration. You can go to Run | Edit Configurations | Templates and enable the option there so that it will be enabled for all run configurations.

This gives you the higher level of integration of the running console (so that you can run your code using Ctrl-Alt-F10 and not by typing the filename in the terminal) and all features of the terminal emulator. This mode is likely to become default in future versions of PyCharm.

Comment: I set "Emulate terminal in output console", then run the code. In the running console it shows no cursor and I could not type anything? Should I set "Run with Python console"?